# Adding multiple list of values to a dictionary doesn't create the same order of values

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I am working with Clarifai's API to write the returned responses to a CSV. For each image I submit, I want to take the top 5 images and append their metadata to a row in a data frame with the file_id as the first column. So each image would have 5 rows with the metadata attached to it in each successive columns. I seem to be generating some dictionary entries where the order of the values in the list being appended isn't preserved and I am trying to figure out why. This is a sample response I am iterating over.

```
    [score: 0.8935652375221252
input {
  id: "1002648140"
  data {
    image {
      url: "https://images.lowes.com/product/converted/192665/192665007798.jpg"
      hosted {
        prefix: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-api/img3/prod"
        suffix: "3617f25f9ee5463497e7abf350091b93/c1ee1a24260772d532f0d371ac08fb06"
        sizes: "orig"
        sizes: "tiny"
        sizes: "small"
        sizes: "large"
      }
    }
    metadata {
      fields {
        key: "cat_entry_id"
        value {
          string_value: "1002648140"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "catalog_name"
        value {
          string_value: "Roses"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "catalog_path"
        value {
          string_value: "Outdoors$Plants & Planters$Plants, Bulbs & Seeds$Roses"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "link_url"
        value {
          string_value: "https://www.lowes.com/pd/Spring-Hill-Nurseries-in-Bare-Root-Red-Flowering-Blaze-Climbing-Rose/1002648140"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "product_name"
        value {
          string_value: "Spring Hill Nurseries in Bare Root Red Flowering Blaze Climbing Rose"
        }
      }
    }
    clusters {
      id: "985_203"
    }
  }
  created_at {
    seconds: 1599796898
    nanos: 391916000
  }
  modified_at {
    seconds: 1599798078
    nanos: 291417000
  }
  status {
    code: INPUT_DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS
    description: "Download complete"
  }
}
annotation {
  id: "c588c2f17f01465f94bde2d2c2e5687f"
  input_id: "1002648140"
  data {
  }
  status {
    code: ANNOTATION_SUCCESS
    description: "Annotation success"
  }
  created_at {
    seconds: 1599798076
    nanos: 759651000
  }
  modified_at {
    seconds: 1599798076
    nanos: 759651000
  }
  model_version_id: "bb186755eda04f9cbb6fe32e816be104"
}
, score: 0.8807249665260315
input {
  id: "1000383061"
  data {
    image {
      url: "https://images.lowes.com/product/converted/743425/743425079649.jpg"
      hosted {
        prefix: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-api/img3/prod"
        suffix: "3617f25f9ee5463497e7abf350091b93/756b268566daea823f07248208c05e21"
        sizes: "orig"
        sizes: "tiny"
        sizes: "small"
        sizes: "large"
      }
    }
    metadata {
      fields {
        key: "cat_entry_id"
        value {
          string_value: "1000383061"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "catalog_name"
        value {
          string_value: "Annuals"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "catalog_path"
        value {
          string_value: "Outdoors$Plants & Planters$Plants, Bulbs & Seeds$Annuals"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "link_url"
        value {
          string_value: "https://www.lowes.com/pd/3-Quart-Purple-Purple-Garden-Mum-in-Pot/1000383061"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "product_name"
        value {
          string_value: " 3-Quart Purple Purple Garden Mum in Pot"
        }
      }
    }
    clusters {
      id: "54_203"
    }
  }
  created_at {
    seconds: 1599795418
    nanos: 883441000
  }
  modified_at {
    seconds: 1599795429
    nanos: 301624000
  }
  status {
    code: INPUT_DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS
    description: "Download complete"
  }
}
annotation {
  id: "91434754e4bd425ba3c528be9cd901e0"
  input_id: "1000383061"
  data {
  }
  status {
    code: ANNOTATION_SUCCESS
    description: "Annotation success"
  }
  created_at {
    seconds: 1599795427
    nanos: 683212000
  }
  modified_at {
    seconds: 1599795427
    nanos: 683212000
  }
  model_version_id: "bb186755eda04f9cbb6fe32e816be104"
}
```

I am using a dictionary and adding the value of metadata as a list and not getting the same order of the lists being appended. Please see the following sample dictionary for reference.

```
{'test_output/fe_IMG_0574.jpg_0': ['Outdoors$Plants & Planters$Plants, Bulbs & Seeds$Roses',
  'https://www.lowes.com/pd/Spring-Hill-Nurseries-in-Bare-Root-Red-Flowering-Blaze-Climbing-Rose/1002648140',
  'Roses',
  'Spring Hill Nurseries in Bare Root Red Flowering Blaze Climbing Rose',
  '1002648140'],
 'test_output/fe_IMG_0574.jpg_1': ['https://www.lowes.com/pd/3-Quart-Purple-Purple-Garden-Mum-in-Pot/1000383061',
  '1000383061',
  ' 3-Quart Purple Purple Garden Mum in Pot',
  'Outdoors$Plants & Planters$Plants, Bulbs & Seeds$Annuals',
  'Annuals'],
 'test_output/fe_IMG_0574.jpg_2': ['https://www.lowes.com/pd/4-Count-Dahlia-Bulbs-L3480/1000151071',
  '1000151071',
  ' 4 Count Dahlia Bulbs (L3480)',
  'Outdoors$Plants & Planters$Plants, Bulbs & Seeds$Plant Bulbs',
  'Plant Bulbs']}
```

which then creates a data frame that has different values for columns in what seems like sporadic rows. This is the code I am using to generate this.

```
final_dict = {}


    for i in range(5):
        response_object = response.hits[i].input.data.metadata.items()
        final_list = []
        url = response_object[0][1]
        product_name = response_object[1][1]
        catalog_entry_id = response_object[2][1]
        catalog_path = response_object[3][1]
        catalog_name = response_object[4][1]

        final_list.append(url)
        final_list.append(catalog_entry_id)
        final_list.append(product_name)
        final_list.append(catalog_path)
        final_list.append(catalog_name)

        final_dict[file_id+'_'+str(i)] = final_list

print(final_dict)
final_df =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_dict, orient='index')
```

Please see the following rows as an example of what I mean
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @martineau I have added a screenshot of what is being added wrong.

Comment: The added screenshot doesn't address the fact that there's way too much unrelated code in your question. Regardless, dictionaries started retaining the order that items are inserted into them officially since Python version 3.7.

Comment: @martineau i have removed the unnecessary code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for posterity. The new Clarifai GRPC client has different data structuring. So as a result, I had to parse them by first listing fields. This is what my final loop looked like. It had the ListFields added line

```
for i in range(5):
    response_object = response.ListFields()[1]
    test_meta = response_object[1][i].input.data.metadata
    final_list = []
    url = test_meta['link_url']
    product_name = test_meta['product_name']
    catalog_entry_id = test_meta['cat_entry_id']
    catalog_path = test_meta['catalog_path']
    catalog_name = test_meta['catalog_name']

    final_list.append(i+1)
    final_list.append(url)
    final_list.append(catalog_entry_id)
    final_list.append(product_name)
    final_list.append(catalog_path)
    final_list.append(catalog_name)

    final_dict[file_id+'_'+str(i)] = final_list
```